# 3D points from Numpy meshgrid coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, geometry

I have a 3 sets of meshgrid coordinates of a 3D cylinder:

```
X, Y, Z = [p1[i] + v[i] * t1 + r * np.sin(theta2) * n1[i] + r * np.cos(theta2) * n2[i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]
```

here the definition of p1, v, t1, r and theta2:

```
r = 3
start = [30, 45, 60]
end = [40, 58, 70]
p1 = np.array(start)
p2 = np.array(end)
v = p2 - p1
mag = scipy.linalg.norm(v)
v = v / mag
not_v = np.array([1, 0, 0])
if (v == not_v).all():
    not_v = np.array([0, 1, 0])
n1 = np.cross(v, not_v)
n1 /= scipy.linalg.norm(n1)
n2 = np.cross(v, n1)
t = np.linspace(0, mag, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
t1, theta2 = np.meshgrid(t, theta)
```

I don't know if I didn't understand correctly how `numpy.meshgrid` works, but I'm looking for a way to get the (x,y,z) points of the polyhedron.

Comment: would...  np.stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()), axis=1) …. work?

Comment: @NaN Yes! It works! Could you please post it as an answer?